# What is a good embedded TLS library? (Cyassl vs Polarssl vs Matrixssl)

Tags: c, ssl, polarssl, wolfssl

I have looked around for good SSL/TLS libraries that support TLS 1.2

I also want to use this library on an embedded platform so it should be **small, easy, secure and free**. It should be a c/c++ library.

So far i have come across Cyassl, Polarssl Matrixssl a lot so i think that one of these should be a good choice (Openssl is way too big).

Now i would like to know *why* people use one over the other.

Thanks

Comment: So my choice: [PolarSSL](https://polarssl.org). Explained my main reasons below.

Comment: As a member of the wolfSSL team (CyaSSL), I can vouch for the fact that we work to improve our documentation, end user experience, and overall quality of the library on a daily basis, and always welcome feedback on how we can further improve.  A helpful link for comparing lightweight SSL libraries is the following Wikipedia article:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TLS_implementations

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok.. Just for starters they all do the same. All three can run on embedded platforms. The difference is where their focus is.

From my personal experience:

- **[PolarSSL](https://polarssl.org)** has loads of documentation, an understandable API, examples, and gives you the ability to actually delve into the code and understand what is happening. In my experience this is a great plus in case you need to debug a specific issue. They only provide Makefile / CMake / MSVC project files, so the task to include it in your embedded environment is yours.
- **[Cyassl](https://www.wolfssl.com)**'s code is harder to understand and tweak. But they have more pre-made Makefiles for specific development platforms. Depending on your environment this might weigh in (for me it rarely does). In a number of comparisons I did as a subcontractor, they are pricier than PolarSSL though.
- Pick [MatrixSSL](http://matrixssl.com) if you don't have budget constraints ;) Definitely the priciest of all and I found no specific reasons to actually use it though in comparison to the alternatives..

With the whole NSA / PRISM thing around: If you want something specifically built in the US, then Cyassl is the best choice. If you want something non-US, PolarSSL is the only sane choice.

So if by **free** you mean: I'm going to use it in an Open Source project, then price does not matter. The verdict from the community: PolarSSL has good adoption in OpenVPN, Cyassl in MySQL.

Comment: matrixssl has the smallest footprint

Comment: Also note that PolarSSL is now part of ARM, so if your embedded target is an ARM it may have sense to use this library instead of the others.